# Server Side Android Application failing to start

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, data-stream

this is my first question and ive been stuck on this unknown problem for day now. The app was running successfully till i added some new code to make a custom listview component and to read some messages from the client.

The MainActivity.java

```
 `public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView info, infoip, msg;
    String message = "";
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
     infoip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
     msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);




     //instantiate custom adapter
     MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(list, this);

     //handle listview and assign adapter
     ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
     lView.setAdapter(adapter);

     infoip.setText(getIpAddress());

     Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
       socketServerThread.start();
     // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }
     public void addOrder(String ordername)
     {
      list.add(ordername);

    }
     @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

       if (serverSocket != null) {
      try {
       serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();

     // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     client.connect();
     Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
          Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
          "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
          // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's    content,
          // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
          // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
          Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
          // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
          Uri.parse("android-app://com.buzzer.ventern.clientservertrial/http/host/path")
  );
  AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
  super.onStop();

       // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
       // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
          Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
          "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
               // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app    activity's content,
             // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
          // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
          Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
          // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
              Uri.parse("android-app://com.buzzer.ventern.clientservertrial/http/host/path")
  );
  AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
  client.disconnect();
 }

 public class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
    String ordername;
  static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
  int count = 0;
    MainActivity ma= new MainActivity();
  @Override
  public void run() {
   Socket socket = null;
   DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
   DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

   try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
      info.setText("I'm waiting here: "
              + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
     }
    });

    while (true) {
     socket = serverSocket.accept();
     dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
             socket.getInputStream());
     dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
             socket.getOutputStream());

     String messageFromClient = "";

     //If no message sent from client, this code will block the program
     messageFromClient = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        ordername=dataInputStream.readUTF();
    ma.addOrder(ordername);
     count++;
     message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
             + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n"
             + "Msg from client: " + messageFromClient + "\n";

     MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
       msg.setText(message);
      }
     });

     String msgReply = "Hello from server, order #" + count+" has been accepted.";
     dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgReply);
        dataOutputStream.flush();


    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    final String errMsg = e.toString();
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
      msg.setText(errMsg);
     }
    });

   } finally {
    if (socket != null) {
     try {
      socket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if (dataInputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataInputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataOutputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  }

 }

 private String getIpAddress() {
  String ip = "";
  try {
   Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
           .getNetworkInterfaces();
   while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
            .nextElement();
    Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
            .getInetAddresses();
    while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
     InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

     if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
      ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "
              + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
     }

    }

   }

  } catch (SocketException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
  }

  return ip;
 }
}`
```

The MyCustomAdapter

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;



    public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return list.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return 0;
        //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);


        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //send acknowledgement to client
                list.remove(position); //or some other task
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="Server V1.0"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="255dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contextClickable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Okay" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I am new to android, and alot of this code is referenced from some android-er posts and some from previous stackoverflow answers. If anyone could tell me why my app crashes when started.

EDIT: Solved the error, but now exception in ASyncTAsk in the client, in doInBackground()
code of the doInBackground() of the client app

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            item=ma.getStr();
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(item);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            response = dataInputStream.readUTF();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }`
```

Comment: post logcat of the exception

Comment: 03-24 18:11:35.074 E/AndroidRuntime(16130): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.buzzer.ventern.clientservertrial/com.buzzer.ventern.clientservertrial.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference @Yazan

Comment: make sure `lView` is not null

Comment: found the problem, fixed it. but now getting an EOFException when trying to connect the client to the server. Is it because of readUTF and writeUTF? @Yazan

Comment: update the question with stacktrace from logcat

Comment: `03-25 11:56:26.483 E/AndroidRuntime(16254): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
03-25 11:56:26.483 E/AndroidRuntime(16254): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

16254 03-25 11 :56:26.483

An- .Caused by:

droidRun- java.lang.NullPointerException:

time Attempt to invoke virtual method
'int java.lang.String.length()' on a
null object reference`

@Yazan

Comment: @AnkitDhame don't post code in the comments, use the `edit` button.

Comment: Solved, changed DataInputStream and DataOutputStream to ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream.